# python3.7 AttributeError about items

Tags: python

```
def showPlt(res):
    res1 = sorted(res.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    ranks = []
    freqs = []
    for rank, value in enumerate(res1):
        ranks.append(rank + 1)
        freqs.append(value[1])
        rank += 1
    plt.loglog(ranks, freqs)
    plt.xlabel('**', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold', fontproperties='SimHei')
    plt.ylabel('**', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold', fontproperties='SimHei')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()

files_path = file_name(r'S:\****')
res = getCharacter(files_path)
showPlt(res)
```

The error message is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "M:/untitled/StoryOfStone.py", line 44, in <module>
    showPlt(res)
File "M:/untitled/StoryOfStone.py", line 28, in showPlt
    res1 = sorted(res.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
```

My function  getCharacter() is as follows:

```
def getCharacter(files_path):
res = {}
for i in  range(1,len(files_path)):
    path = files_path[i]
    for x in open(path,'rb').read().decode('utf-8'):
        if 19968 <= ord(x) <= 40869:
            res[x] = res.get(x,0) + 1
```

I really don't know what's wrong with `items()`. And the version of my python is 3.70 . If anyone can fix this ? Thanks!

Comment: As it says: res is None. Have a look at which argument you pass

Comment: What is `res` that you're passing to the function?

Comment: Unindented code makes me nervous... Where does `getCharacter` come from?!

Comment: Either `getCharacter()` doesn't work, or it sometimes returns `None` normally and you need to check for that before calling `showPlt()`.

Comment: Thank u very much , I'll check it latter .

Comment: You should learn to read error messages. It says `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'`. So the 'NoneType' object must be `res`. Now look where `res` comes from. It's a parameter. Where does this parameter come from? It's the `getCharacter` function. Now you can look there.

Comment: My getCharacter() method has been posted above, I still don't understand where this method is wrong, can anyone help me modify it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This means that `res` is `None`, and therefore you can't call any of the usual methods on it. Make sure that your `getCharacter` method never returns `None` and then try again.

Comment: So,  maybe it's  because the method getCharacter() gets nothing from my file, is that right?

Comment: @Louisely I can't see your function, but that may be it.

Comment: I have just posted my function getCharacter() above, could you help me to modify it? Thank you!